# How to use SignalR with Redis scale-out backend in a console application or worker role?

Tags: signalr, signalr-hub, signalr-backplane

I have a web app that uses SignalR with Redis scale-out (allegedly) and hubs, and that works fine. Now I need a worker role to be able to send messages to all connected clients but I'm not sure how to do it. I also have a console application that serves as a test app which runs the methods immediately that the worker will run periodically.

Hosting a web server within the worker or console app seems odd, but that's mostly I've found so far. Talking to the web app seems odd also. Shouldn't it be able to just post a message to Redis and all the subscribers pick it up?

This is the code I'm using. I copied the `UseRedis` call and the `handleExecutedAction` pretty much verbatim from the web app. It doesn't throw or anything but the message doesn't get to the web client:

```
GlobalHost.DependencyResolver.UseRedis(new RedisScaleoutConfiguration("...", "..."));
var hubContext = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<WebUI.EventHub>();
hubContext.Clients.All.handleExecutedAction(new Action { Type = "testing" });
```

I used this method (the context) after finding [this](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-server#callfromoutsidehub) page. I know the client is working because other messages come through from the web app, just nothing from the console app...

Comment: I got it to work by installing OWIN and running a local web server, but I think it's pretty ridiculous if that's really necessary...so I'm hoping there is a better way to dispatch messages.